# Call to undefined function when I insert data in my table

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

```
$query = "insert into fs_is_temp (maincode,acode,amount,periodfrom,periodto,danoun,period,fyear,frequency,stype,sseq)
values('".$value['maincode']."', '".$value['acode']. "','". $value['amount'] ."','". STR_TO_DATE($value['periodfrom'],'%Y-%m-%d') ."','".STR_TO_DATE($value['periodto'],'%Y-%m-%d') ."','".$value['danounc'] ."','". $value['period'] . "','". $value['fyear']."','". $value['frequency']. "','". $value['stype'] . "','". $value['sseq']. "')";
```

When I execute this query they show:

> Call to undefined function STR_TO_DATE()

Any body can help me?

Answer (score 1):

STR_TO_DATE is mysql function, not PHP, so your code would be like this

```
    $query = "insert into fs_is_temp (maincode,acode,amount,periodfrom,periodto,danoun,period,fyear,frequency,stype,sseq)
                                    values('".$value['maincode']."', '".$value['acode']. "','". $value['amount'] ."', 
STR_TO_DATE('".$value['periodfrom']."','%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE('".$value['periodto']."','%Y-%m-%d'),'".$value['danounc'] ."','". $value['period'] . "','". $value['fyear']."','". $value['frequency']. "','". $value['stype'] . "','". $value['sseq']. "')";
```

Comment: they not changing format that function STR_TO_DATE('".$value['periodfrom']."' when i print query insert into fs_is_temp (maincode,acode,amount,periodfrom,periodto,danoun)
values('10190', 'F2IN200000','1061',STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2010','%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE('30-09-2011','%Y-
%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE('30-11-2011','%Y-%m-%d'))

Comment: STR_TO_DATE('".$value['periodfrom']."','%Y-%m-%d') not format change i want to store data this format like, 2016-10-01 but when i add str_to_date in $query they remove th error but format will pass same this 01-10-2016

Comment: i think you use the STR_TO_DATE like this: STR_TO_DATE('30-09-2011‌​','%d-%m-%Y'), the second parameter is the input date format, not your desire date format